# LINQ Dictionary Non-Distinct Values

Tags: c#, .net, linq, list, linq-group

I am struggeling a little with trying to write the LINQ query to do the following,

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int ID {get; set;}
    public int Name {get; set;}
    public IEnumerable<string> SomeIEnumerable {get; set;}
}
```

I am trying to create the object using LINQ from a DB query that would return something as follows,

```
ID    Name     SomeString
0     NameA    "MyValue"
1     NameB    "Value1"
1     NameB    "Value2"
2     NameC    "Value"
```

The LINQ is pretty easy to write as well,

```
from DataRow row in dataSet.Tables[0].Rows
select new MyClass
{
    ID = (int)row["ID"],
    Name = row["Name"].ToString(),
    SomeIEnumerable = new List<string>{ row["SomeString"].ToString() }
};
```

The tricky part is how do I turn this into a Dictionary where
dictionary[1].SomeIEnumerable = {"Value1", "Value2"}

A simple ToDictionary would throw an `ArgumentException`

The main issue here, is how do I handle the fact that the keyis not distinct, and be able to lookup in the temporary dictionary the existing value to add to it the values I am interested in.

Comment: Keys needs to distinct, for that you can select only distinct rows by id.

Comment: Your “pretty easy” LINQ wouldn't work, because `Add()` returns `void`. But something like `new List<string>{ (string)row["SomeString"] }` would.

Comment: @svick thanks, adjust my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also your grouping, and then use IGrouping to retrieve the list of items in the group

Sample code

```
    var simulatedData = Enumerable.Range(0,10).Select(x=> new {Key=x%3+1, Index=x}); 
    var dict = simulatedData.GroupBy(x=>x.Key).ToDictionary(x=>x.Key, x=>x.Select(t=>t.Index));
```

Comment: Thank you, will paste me answer in a second

Answer (score 3):

Instead of calling `ToDictionary`, call [`ToLookup`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb353368). :)

Answer (score 1):

Answer thanks to @Tilak is,

```
from DataRow row in dataSet.Tables[0].Rows
group row by new
{
    ID = (int) row["ID"],
    Name = row["Name].ToString()
} into rowGroup
select new MyClass
{
    ID = rowGroup.Key.ID,
    Name = rowGroup.Key.Name,
    SomeIEnumerable =
        from row in rowGroup
        select row["SomeString"].ToString()
};
```